# I wonder if NSTableViewCell could have wide cell than it's width (hidden contents)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

UITableview only has one volume and some cell could move it's contents left or right using swift to see it's hidden(?) contents.

like

| --- iPhone width --------- |

| --- showing contents --- | hidden contents |

I would like to make my NSTableViewCell like UITableViewCell but I don't even know what API should I look at. (my cell will have only one column and has inner cells.)

And not even sure that is possible or not.

Could you tell me little direction for that.  (at least, it's possible or not)

thank you.

Comment: You add views to a cell's `contentView`.  These subviews can be positioned with frames or constraints using offsets.  Either way, if you use an origin that is outside the bounds of the `contentView`, you will position the subview visually partially or totally outside the cell.

Comment: @par thanks~ it means there's no api so i need to handle everything like capturing mouse and moving subview as mouse moving (swifing) and so on, right??

Comment: Yes, but that's no different from any other gesture handling, although you may have issues with the automatic pan gesture handling already tracking scrolling in the tableview, but it's not that hard to deal with.